# How to use Django custom user tables are not extended user model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

custom use model

```
    class CustomUser(models.Model):
        account = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.CustomUser'
```

How can I use the custom model to complete the functions of registration and login, can you give me some advice or references?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom user model is not same as other models. Task needs to be completed

1. Custom User model should inherit "AbstractBaseUser" model.
2. Make sure "USERNAME_FIELD", "REQUIRED_FIELDS" are defined in custom user model.
3. Define Custom user manager for custom user model that overrides "create_user", "create_staff" and "create_superuser" methods that provide flexibility while creating users.

## Custom User Manager

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def save_user(self, email, password, mobile_number, **other_fields):
    if not email:
          raise ValueError(_('Please provide valid email address.'))
      user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), mobile_number=mobile_number, **other_fields)
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save()
    # Add any permissions or groups to the user.
    return user
      
    
  def create_user(self, email, password, mobile_number, **other_fields):
    # set any fields of CustomUser to True or False depending on the role
    # Perform any customization required to the field values.
    # make sure user doesn't have additional privileges.
    return save_user(self, email, password, mobile_number, **other_fields)
  
  def create_staff(self, email, password, mobile_number, **other_fields):
    # set any fields of CustomUser to True or False depending on the role
    # Perform any customization required to the field values.
    # Make sure user has staff related privilege by setting corresponding field
    # to true.
    return save_user(self, email, password, mobile_number, **other_fields)
  
  def create_superuser(self, email, password, mobile_number, **other_fields):
    # set any fields of CustomUser to True or False depending on the role
    # Perform any customization required to the field values.
    # Make sure user has superuser related privilege by setting corresponding
    # field to true.
    return save_user(self, email, password, mobile_number, **other_fields)
```

[image]

Comment: Now I already have a background user table, and the background user table cannot use the same user table as the normal user table, what should I do at this time? Background users and ordinary users are not the same url to log in and register. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you have already developed the app using an in-built User table? If you have built an app using default User table, what are the customization are you looking in your user model?

Comment: class BackgroundUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(' max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)                                                                             This is Django's built-in User model. Now I also need a user table for ordinary users. I need to complete the login and registration of ordinary users. What should I do?

Comment: May i know, what do you mean by ordinary users? Is it possible if you setup code sandbox so that i can help you. I am bit confused with your requirement.

Comment: Only two user models are needed, BackgroundUser logs in to the background management system, and CustomUser logs in to the home page. The two user models cannot be combined.

Comment: My advice would be use one custom user modal with in-built flags and additional fields that distinguish between background user and normal user. If there are fields specific to normal user, you can create "NormalUserProfile" and have onetoone field with "CustomUser" same thing can be applied to the background user. With having one custom user model, maintenance will be easy. If you share more information on your requirement and code, we can work on that.